# How to return a subcollection (or object) in json without including all attributes

Tags: json, node.js, mongoose

I am using `mongoose` as `JSON Schema` and `node.js` with it. Need not say, I am new to both. I have been struggling through the day to get this thing work for me but couldn't. Finally, the only solution was to get help from some real nice people out here.

Here is my schema definition -

```
UserName = {    
        "properties": {
            userURL: {
                    "description": "URL of this resource",
                        "type": "string"
                },
            userName : {
                    "description": "UserName",
                    "type": "string",
                    "required": true
                },
        }
}
```

When I make a get call to it, it returns the response in following format -

```
[
  {
    "_id": "54c5ede55c82c4bd6abee50a",
    "__v": 0,
    "properties": {
    "userURL": "http://localhost:3000/54c1d6ae441ae900151a6520",
    "userName ": "testUser"
    }
  }
]
```

Now my requirement is to return the response in following format -

```
[
  {
    "_id": "54c5ede55c82c4bd6abee50a",
    "userURL": "http://localhost:3000/54c1d6ae441ae900151a6520",
    "userName ": "testUser"
  }
]
```

i.e without version and properties tags. I am able to get away with version using following code but properties seems to be tricky thing -

```
 .get(function(request, response) {
        UserSchemaModel.find().select('properties.userURL properties.userName').exec (function (err, resObj) {
            if (err)
                response.send(err);
            else{           
                response.json(resObj);
            }
        });
    });
```

But it still has properties field :( -

```
[
 {
    "_id": "54c5ede55c82c4bd6abee50a",
    "properties": {
    "userURL": "http://localhost:3000/54c1d6ae441ae900151a6520",
    "userName ": "testUser"
    }
 }
]
```

I did some google around `select as`, `alias name in select`,`population` in mongoose but no luck.

Kindly suggest. With best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a new object

```
response.json(
              {
               "_id":     resObj["_id"], 
               "userURL": resObj["properties"]["userUrl"], 
               "userName": resObj["properties"]["userName"]
              }
           );
```

**Update:** Since resObj is an array (as per your comment), you can use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform them into the right format like so:

```
response.json( resObj.map(function(o){
                 return {
                          "_id":      o["_id"], 
                          "userURL":  o["properties"]["userUrl"], 
                          "userName": o["properties"]["userName"]
                        };
                    }) 
                 );
```

This will return a list of transformed objects that then get passed into the `response.json()` method.

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work. `"userURL": resObj["properties"]["userURL"]
                               ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'userURL' of undefined` I tried with `resObj.properties.userURL` earlier, but same error.

Comment: mate you gave me a clue and I am a step ahead. resObj is a collection of json objects and hence `resObj[0]` seems to be working. Any pointers as how to loop over all the objects and get it working? As we can send `response` object only once.

Comment: Awesomeness !! Thanks a ton !! Works like a charm !! Would you like to point me to some good resources for methods like `Array.prototype.map()`. It was a great help indeed.

Comment: If you are interested in the topic, you could read about `higher order functions` as a general programming paradigm. This article explains some things using javascript: http://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html